# 回文かどうかを調べる関数がわかりません。

Tags: python, python3

問題は「与えられた単語が回文かどうかを調べる関数 isPalindrome を定義しなさい」です。

テストコード

print(isPalindrome('Madam'))
print(isPalindrome('hello'))
True
False

Comment: 問題の答えがわからないのか、テストコードの意味か目的がわからないのか、どちらですか？

Comment: スタックオーバーフローではプログラムの作成依頼的な質問は回答が集まりづらい傾向があります。動かなくても構わないのでご自身が試したテストコードや試行錯誤した履歴を載せるととより回答が集まりやすいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

スライス[::-1]
Upper
を組み合わせればなんとかなりそう

Answer (score 0):

回文かどうかを調べる関数を作成し、回文であればTrue、回文でなければFalseを返す関数を作成することになります。従って
1 引数の文字の一番最初と一番最後を比較し、同じでなければFalseをかえす。
2 引数の頭から2番目と、最後から2番目を比較し、同じでなければFalseをかえす。
3 引数の頭から3番目と、最後から3番目を比較し、同じでなければFalseをかえす。
4 上記の処理を文字列の最後まで繰り返し、FalseにならなければTrueを返す。
文字列が偶数の場合はいいですが、奇数の場合は真ん中の文字は何でもいいことになりますので、
注意が必要です。
例
ABBAは回文
ABCBAも回文
ABCABは回文じゃない。

というような、プログラムを書くことになります。